# Scroll UITextView when keyboard appears in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uitextfield, uitextview

The problem I am facing now is that there is a UITextField in UIScrollView.
When i clicks the UITextField, i am showing UIPickerView with UIToolBar. I need to move UITextField to up when PickerView presents.

Here is my design
[image]

Here is my code

```
 func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification)
{
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo
    if let info = userInfo
    {
        let animationDurationObject =
        info[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as NSValue

        let keyboardEndRectObject =
        info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as NSValue

        var animationDuration = 0.0
        var keyboardEndRect = CGRectZero

        animationDurationObject.getValue(&animationDuration)
        keyboardEndRectObject.getValue(&keyboardEndRect)

        let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow

        keyboardEndRect = view.convertRect(keyboardEndRect, fromView: window)

        let intersectionOfKeyboardRectAndWindowRect =
        CGRectIntersection(view.frame, keyboardEndRect);

        UIView.animateWithDuration(animationDuration, animations: {[weak self] in

            self!.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0,
                left: 0,
                bottom: intersectionOfKeyboardRectAndWindowRect.size.height,
                right: 0)
            self?.scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(self!.activeTextField.frame, animated: true)
        })
    }
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification)
{
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo

    if let info = userInfo{
        let animationDurationObject =
        info[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey]
            as NSValue

        var animationDuration = 0.0;

        animationDurationObject.getValue(&animationDuration)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(animationDuration, animations: {
            [weak self] in
            self?.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
            self?.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        })
    }
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool
{
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool
{
    var returnVal = true
    self.activeTextField = textField
    if textField == self.pickerTextField
    {
        returnVal = false
        var yval:CGFloat = self.view.bounds.size.height - 206
        self.pickerContainerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, yval, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.pickerContainerView.frame.size.height)
        self.pickerContainerView.hidden = false
        self.view.addSubview(self.pickerContainerView)
    }
    return returnVal
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    self.activeTextField = nil
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

When i click other TextFields, those TextField goes up when keyboard presents. But what to do for PickerTextField

Any ideas for UItextView too

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Swift 3 Version:

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    let scrollPoint : CGPoint = CGPoint.init(x:0, y:textView.frame.origin.y)
    self.scrollView.setContentOffset(scrollPoint, animated: true)
}

func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    self.scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 You can try like below with textView delegate - 

 // MARK: UITextViewDelegate
    func textViewDidBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) {
        var scrollPoint : CGPoint = CGPointMake(0, self.textView.frame.origin.y)
        self.scrollView.setContentOffset(scrollPoint, animated: true)
    }

    func textViewDidEndEditing(textView: UITextView) {
        self.scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPointZero, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: I tried your code. Its not working for my condition. I am getting TextView y value as 93. Because i added TextView inside of UIView. U can see this in my design.

Comment: You should add your textView in scrollView and it will work then. You must inherit textViewDelegate in your view Controller as well as set the delegate of textView in storyboard.